# Sync One Way using rsync

Tags: rsync, one-way-sync

Is it possible to do the following with rsync:

I need to sync all files with the extension .zip from all subdirectories of a certain folder to another single folder. I need all the files to be copied to the same folder.

Also it needs to be one way so that if a file is deleted in the destination directory the file will not be copied over again on the next sync. This will all be done on the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do this directly.  If you say don't copy ones that aren't on the destination it wouldn't transfer new files.